# Visual Studio 2019 -> Property Editor ?changed

Tags: xcode, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 -> Property Editor

Is there any way to configure property editor
to show only changed properties?

or in other way...
configure color of changed properties...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by installing `ReSharper` you can have some color changes when you active identify colors

> Options->Code inspection->check Color Identifiers

But in **VS** we do not have this feature.